# PHP: MYSQLI - Get data from same row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have taken to this data that are the same but presented only one here

now I want to get `text` from last row

```
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT DISTINCT `sent_by`, `sent_to` FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_by` = '1' OR `sent_to` = '1'"); 
if($sql_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($fetch_data = $sql_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if($fetch_data["sent_by"] == 1) {
            echo $fetch_data["sent_to"]. " TEXT: ". $fetch_data["text"].  </br>";
        } else {
            echo $fetch_data["sent_by"]. " TEXT: ". $fetch_data["text"].  </br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Database structure:

[image: Check Image Here]

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: The `text` is not in your select statement!

Comment: @Accountantم when i add i not get same data

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

If you have field `id` as auto increment field, then you can get the last row with this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `sent_by`, `sent_to`, `id`, `text` FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_by` = '1' OR `sent_to` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

So change this:

```
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT DISTINCT `sent_by`, `sent_to` FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_by` = '1' OR `sent_to` = '1'");
```

on this:

```
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT DISTINCT `sent_by`, `sent_to`, `id`, `text` FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_by` = '1' OR `sent_to` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

In this new query you sort all results by the value of `id` field in descending order.

If you will remove `DISTINCT` from your query, you can remove also `id` from SELECT list in your query.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Freensi do `echo $connection->error` and see the error

Comment: ORDER BY NOT WORK I GET ERROR

Comment: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'new_database.chat.id' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

Comment: Why did you add id to the fields list?

Comment: Because @Freensi got the error `SELECT list, references column 'new_database.chat.id' which is not in SELECT list`. But if you will remove  `DISTINCT ` from your SQL query, you can remove `id` from your SELECT fields.

Comment: @AlexanderReznikov thank you but this is not answer, i don't need to repeat same data

Comment: You don't have to do this! Just use query from my answer with `DISTINCT` and `id` in the select list.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark it as solution and vote up.

Answer (score 0):

remove DISTINCT , and create query just

```
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT sent_by, sent_to FROM chat WHERE sent_by = '1' OR `sent_to` = '1'");
```